# Samsung Gear 360 corrupted SD card - How to recover

Tags: file-corruption, micro-sd-card, virtual-reality

How do I recover a corrupted Samsung Gear 360 SD card?

Everytime I take a picture it throws an error, and when I plug the card into my computer it shows as blank, or throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Linux, I know there's similar software out there for windows, but for Linux you can use `testdisk`'s `photorec` on the Gear 360's `exFAT` partition:

```
sudo apt install testdisk exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Insert the Samsung SD card into computer via adapter

```
sudo photorec
```

Make sure you select the SD Card, then run a `Whole` recovery on the partition. All your images/videos should come off the disk.

AFTER successful recovery, You may have to format the SD Card again with the Gear 360's settings menu, (I had to do it off a fresh insert). Don't forget you need Action Director to re-project the 360 photos